# xy diagram: set height of a specific row

Tags: spacing, diagrams, xy-pic

I'm using the `xy` package. In the diagram

```
$$\xymatrix@R=8mm@C=8mm{  
    & 1\ar@{-}[ddl]\ar@{-}[dr] &  \\
    & & c\ar@{-}[dd]\\
  a & & \\
    & & b\\
    & 0\ar@{-}[uul]\ar@{-}[ur] &  \\}$$
```

[image],

How can I set the row height between `c` and `a` and between `a` and `b` to be smaller. I want to create this diagram:

[image]

`\\[2mm]` doesn't make any change, and `\xymatrix@R=8mm@C=8mm{...` only makes global changes.

Comment: Is `tikz` or `pstricks` an option for you?

Comment: @Marco: If my problem can't be solved via `xy`, then `\usepackage{tikz}` is certainly an option :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used `xymatrix`, and couldn't find anything useful in the manual, after a little searching, but I can provide a TikZ-solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (thing) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=15pt] {
  &[1cm] 1 &[0.5cm] \\
  &        & c      \\[-15pt]
a &        &        \\[-15pt]
  &        & b      \\
  & 0      &        \\
};
\draw (thing-1-2) -- (thing-2-3) -- (thing-4-3) -- (thing-5-2);
\draw (thing-1-2) -- (thing-3-1) -- (thing-5-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, perhaps an unecessary answer. One difference between me and the answer of @Marco is that I defined different column separations, as that seemed to be the case in the reference screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best that I could do with `Xy-pic`.  The idea is to make the c and b special (off-matrix) targets *à la* Section 3.3 of [`xyguide.pdf`](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[matrix,arrow]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix @R=12mm @C=8mm {
& 1\ar@{-}[dl] 
& \save[]+<0mm,-8mm>*{c} \ar@{-}[l] \restore  \\
a & 
& \save[]+<0mm,-8mm>*{d} \ar@{-}[ld] \ar@{-}+<0mm,12mm> \restore  \\
& 0\ar@{-}[ul] & \\
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

The fact that you got two good TikZ answers in the time that it took to get one bad Xy-pic answer indicates the ease of crafting TikZ code.  If you're still persuadable I would encourage you to learn TikZ.

Comment: "I would encourage you to learn TikZ" - agreed, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Just add rows and close up them:

```
\xymatrix@R=2mm@C=8mm{
  & 1 \ar@{-}[dddl] \ar@{-}[ddr] \\ \\
  & & c \ar@{-}[dd] \\ 
  a \ar@{-}[dddr] \\ 
  & & b \ar@{-}[ddl] \\ \\
  & 0
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the relation to the comment of of Leon:

> {tikz} is certainly an option

I would suggest something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
    \[\xymatrix@R=8mm@C=8mm{
        & 1\ar@{-}[ddl]\ar@{-}[dr] &  \\
        & & c\ar@{-}[dd]\\
      a & & \\
        & & b\\
        & 0\ar@{-}[uul]\ar@{-}[ur] &  \\
    }\]

    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,remember picture,]
    \matrix (n) [matrix of math nodes,%
    column sep=8mm,
    row sep=8mm,nodes={anchor=center},]
    {
        & 1 &  \\
        &   & c\\
      a &   &  \\[-4mm]
        &   & b\\[-4mm]
        & 0 &  \\
    };
    \draw (n-1-2) -- (n-3-1);
    \draw (n-1-2) -- (n-2-3);
    \draw (n-3-1) -- (n-5-2);
    \draw (n-4-3) -- (n-5-2);
    \draw (n-4-3) -- (n-2-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [`pstricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) solution to drawing this diagram. It uses [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) to identify node locations/connections and [`multido`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multido) to iterate over the nodes, arranged in a circle of radius `2cm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
  \SpecialCoor% Enable polar coordinates (r;t)
  \newcommand{\radius}{2cm}% Radius of diagram
  \psset{linestyle=solid,linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=black,nodesep=10pt}% Edge parameters
  \rput{180}{%
    \degrees[5]% 5 angles per revolution (each angle is 360/5=72 degrees)
    \pnode(\radius;0){node-0}% Root note
    \multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=1+1}{5}{%
      \pnode(\radius;\iB){node-\iB}% Node
      \pcline(node-\iA)(node-\iB)% Edge
    }
  }

  % Labels
  \rput{0}(node-0){$a$}%
  \rput{0}(node-1){$0$}%
  \rput{0}(node-2){$b$}%
  \rput{0}(node-3){$c$}%
  \rput{0}(node-4){$1$}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `psmatrix`.

Comment: Thanks - I draw it as to be more circular rather than rectangular which is not that easy with `psmatrix`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to use `\xymatrixrowsep{<width>}`, e.g. `1.2cm` and `\xymatrixcolsep{<width>}`, e.g. `2.4cm`.